# jabra headset's microphone does not show up in sound control

Tags: sound, 12.10, microphone

I have just updated to 12.10, and I noticed that my headset's microphone is not showing up in the recording tab of the sound settings.

But! Using the Pulse Audio Manager, the microphone is there and recognized. It is just not showing up in the sound settings that you can access from the icon besides the clock, and therefore, I cant use it, or dont know how.

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of headset is it? Bluetooth? USB? Do you have a type number to be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to delete the bluetooth settup for the device and set it up again.  Once it's installed correctly and is connected via Bluetooth it should definitely show up in the sound settings.  My Jabra Wave is working great with 12.10, but after connecting I still have to open sound settings and change the input and output to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: pulseaudio volume control]

You may need to go to the Configuration tab and choose the HSP profile, that is, after you have installed pipewire, if necessary.